# How and when host CPU state is saved in the VMCS host-state area?

Tags: x86, intel, virtualization, hypervisor, vt-x

I'm trying to understand the basics of how Intel VMX/VT-x works. In the Intel Software Developer Manual it says this about VMCS:

> The VMCS data are organized into six logical groups:
> **Guest-state area**. Processor state is saved into the guest-state area
> on VM exits and loaded from there on VM entries.
> **Host-state area**. Processor state is loaded from the host-state area on
> VM exits.
> ...

It makes sense to me that the CPU state is saved into the guest-area on VM exits and loaded on VM entries. It also makes sense that the CPU state is loaded from the host-state area on VM exits... but when is the CPU state saved in the host-state area? Intuitively I would say that it is saved on VM entries, but the manual doesn't say so... can somebody help me clarify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPU never saves the host state.
The VMM (aka: the hypervisor) controls when to execute `vmlaunch/vmresume` and can thus set the host state area accordingly before their execution.

When a VM-entry fails due to an invalid VMCS, the execution falls through to the next instruction after `vmlaunch/vmresume`.
When the VM-entry fails due to an invalid guest state, the execution resumes from the  `RIP` set in the host state area (just like a VM-exit occurred).
If the CPU were to set the host state area, the two cases will be identical.

This is also why the CPU *checks* the host state area before entering VMX non-root mode (i.e. launching a VM).